# Don't compress files when using node-uglify

Tags: angularjs, uglifyjs

I am using uglify-js to concatenate all of JS files together and create a map for them, but I don't want to have it compress the code as that seems to be causing problems in angular due to the variable name changes (yeah, this is something that later should be changed in the code).

```
    var output_filename = '/compiled.js'
var output_file_path = '/public' + output_filename;
var fs = require('fs');

var result = UglifyJS.minify(compiled_script_paths, {
    outSourceMap: output_filename + '.map',
    compress: false,
    type:'no-compress'
});
fs.writeFile(output_file_path, result.code, function(a, b, c){console.log('abc', a, b, c)});
fs.writeFile(output_file_path + '.map', result.map, function(err){});
```

I tried two different options (one from minify's documentation) to stop it from compressing, but still does compression.

How do I stop it?

Note: I am using "uglify-js": "^2.6.4"

Comment: Instead of turning off the compression, why not use a tool such as ng-annotate to insert all the annotations needed to make your code compressible?

Comment: Not to answer your questions but just to add my two cents (there really are two of them): 1. you can avoid minification problems in angular by properly annotating dependencies ([see here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification)); 2. I have made really good experiences with Webpack for concatenating and bundling files.

Comment: Yep, long run, fixing all of the code would be ideal, but I am just looking to concatenate everything together today without compressing it.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
compress: true,
mangle: {
    keep_fnames: true
}
```